# How to update chart that linked to MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, charts, updates

I have a chart that linked to MySQL database. I want to update the chart every second.
I use the code below to load the Database to my chart :

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(" select * from konsentrasi.okedeh ;", conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                chart1.Series["konsentrasi"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetInt32("nomor"), myReader.GetInt32("konsentrasi"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Then I use timer to update the chart :

```
chart1.Update();
```

But nothing in the chart changed. So, what should I do to update the chart?
And how I can scroll the chart to load just some data. For example it only show 10 data?

Comment: if you use the debugger and set a breakpoint to a piece of code in the code where the timer should jump in, does it work ? I mean do you get to the debugging-point ?

Comment: I've found the way to update the chart, all I need to do is load the data to chart, remove it and then load again using timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an ORDER clause to your SQL (probably DESC for some timestamp or ID) and a LIMIT clause to get only the last 10 records. Something like that:

```
SELECT * from konsentrasi.okedeh ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the limit is working.
And now remain 1 question. How to update the chart? since the 'chart1.Update();' is not working.

Comment: I've found the way to update the chart, all I need to do is load the data to chart, remove it and then load again using timer.